# Bootstrap Carousel : Remove auto slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap Carousel.  All I want is that the slider will only slide when a navigation or a pagination is clicked. 
I've tried removing

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 6000
});
```

It works fine but my problem is once I've already clicked a navigation or pagination, it is now auto sliding. Is it possible to remove the auto sliding function? If so, how?

Answer (score 298, accepted):

You can do this 2 ways, via js or html (easist)

1. **Via js**

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: false,
});
```

That will make the auto sliding stop because there no Milliseconds added and will never slider next.

2. **Via Html**  By adding `data-interval="false"` and removing `data-ride="carousel"`

```
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

becomes:

```
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
```

**updated based on @webMan's comment**

Comment: get rid also of the `data-ride="carousel"` ... and correct syntax for inline: `data-interval="false"`

Comment: any idea how to stop carousel when using `react-bootstrap`?

Comment: It's `data-bs-interval="false"` now

Comment: data-bs-interval would be for bootstrap v5

Answer (score 116):

From the [official docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel):

> **interval** The amount of time to delay between automatically cycling an item. *If **false**, carousel will not automatically cycle.*

You can either pass this value with javascript or using a `data-interval="false"` attribute.

Comment: thanks for the data-interval='false', the easy option if you are using a `the-bootstrap` theme in Wordpress

Comment: `data-interval="false"` is the much better solution, no need to touch the bootstrap JS!

Comment: This is not working for me <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel-ex" data-interval="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner" >.... and nothing... still autosliding

Comment: This is indeed much simpler for simple cases, but do **keep in mind** it's a much better design to use your custom `scripts.js` and keep no script coding in the html! ;)

Answer (score 63):

You just need to add one more attribute to your DIV tag which is

```
data-interval="false"
```

no need to touch JS!

Answer (score 41):

Change/Add to data-interval="false"  on carousel div

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="false" id="myCarousel">
```

Answer (score 10):

In Bootstrap v5 use: `data-bs-interval="false"`

```
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="false">
```

Answer (score 9):

Please try the following:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        $('.carousel').carousel('pause');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That's the only one that worked with me on run-time using the console.

Answer (score 4):

data-interval="false"

Add this to the corresponding div ...

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#media').carousel({
    pause: true,
    interval: 40000,
  });
});
```

By using the above script, you will be able to move the images automaticaly

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#media').carousel({
    pause: true,
    interval: false,
  });
});
```

By using the above script, `auto-rotation` will be blocked because `interval` is `false`

Answer (score -1):

Omitting the **data-bs-ride** may work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).