# Bootstrap Carousel Controls Responding but need them to be more precise

Tags: bootstrap-carousel

How to make controls in the bootstrap carousel to change slides only when being clicked on? (I have text in my website and it makes it difficult for users to fill out the application)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Carousel : Remove auto slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977392/bootstrap-carousel-remove-auto-slide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#options) (assuming you're using Bootstrap 4) you have to add `data-interval="false"` to the element you're using for the carousel.

If you're initiating the carousel with JavaScript and want to keep all the options and configs in one place, add `interval: false` to your configuration.

Comment: Thank you! I am using bootstrap 4.So I just add this where?

Comment: On the HTML element that has the class `carousel`, with the application inside it.