# I want to create a dynamic carousel bootstrap banner in PHP

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4, slider

I try to bootstrap sliding banner where some others articles available to this same platform but it was not helpful so I try to make my function learn from some articles and basic PHP.
I am using PDO because I am fresher and in learning stage this is my startup course.

My script not showing any error or result as I am expected, Please help me Where I am mistake and how to I fix this.

Please help me.

**PHP**

```
define('DB_USER',''); // DB Username
define('DB_PASS',''); // DB User Password
define('DB_NAME',''); // DB Name

//DB Connection an established 

try {
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME,DB_USER, DB_PASS);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'We are not able to connect with Database';
    exit;
}
function make_query($con) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `tb_banner` ORDER BY `ID` ASC";
        $result = $con->prepare($query);
        return $result;
    }

function make_slide_indicators($con) {
    $output = ''; 
    $count = 0;
    $result = make_query($con);
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
        if($count == 0) {
            $output .= '
                <li data-target="#dynamic_slide_show" data-slide-to="'.$count.'" class="active"></li>
                ';
        } else {
            $output .= '
                <li data-target="#dynamic_slide_show" data-slide-to="'.$count.'"></li>
                ';
        }
        $count = $count + 1;
    }
    return $output;
}

function make_slides($con) {
    $output = '';
    $count = 0;
    $result = make_query($con);
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
        if($count == 0) {
            $output .= '<div class="item active">';
        } else {
            $output .= '<div class="item">';
        }

      $output .= '
        <img src="'.$row["image"].'" alt="'.$row["banner_caption"].'" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>'.$row["banner_caption"].'</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        ';
        $count = $count + 1;
    }
    return $output;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="page-slider">
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-slider">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators carousel-indicators-frontend">
      <?php echo make_slide_indicators($con); ?>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <?php echo make_slides($con); ?>
      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control carousel-control-shop carousel-control-frontend" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control carousel-control-shop carousel-control-frontend" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php exit(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: its a waste of server resources to load user-end cosmetics :/ thats what JS is for.

Comment: yes, but I want to make this dynamically .. is there any solution.. thank you for your suggestion. but I was not expected that..

Comment: dynamic = auto switch images? check https://stackoverflow.com/a/43997345/7554793

Comment: or a full instruction like: https://medium.com/better-programming/make-a-slideshow-with-automatic-and-manual-controls-using-html-css-and-javascript-b7e9305168f9 . In any case its javascript, not php :/ PHP is to load page resources, JS is to display them.